# Compress video file size with gstreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer, h.264

I am trying to play locally, stream to an address and save the video concurrently with gstreamer

This is the command line code I have been using

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src !  video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! timeoverlay ! tee name="local" \
local. ! queue ! autovideosink \
local. ! queue ! vpuenc_h264  bitrate=3000 ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.50.112 port=5100 \
local. ! queue ! vpuenc_h264  bitrate=3000 ! matroskamux name=mux  ! filesink location=camera.mkv
```

The command line did what it is supposed to ie I can play capture video locally, stream to another location, and store captured video locally as a file

However, I find the stored video size too be too large for h264 video but i thought I have it encoded as h264 file. I reckon I did something wrong in storage part but i couldnt find the error

Need your help and if possible, ways to improve the pipeline

Thanks

Comment: How big is the file, what was your expectation? Did you check the resulting file with `ffprobe` to see if the resulting bitrate matches your set one?

Comment: @FlorianZwoch: for me it is not what i am having now in terms of gb for 2-3 mins of video

Answer (score 1):

You're asking it for a 3kbps `bitrate=3000` bitrate.  That's lower than the low limit, which is 10kbps. But even 10kbps will look really awful.

kbps means kilobits (1000, not 1024) bits per second.